# Swift generics and specialization

Tags: swift, generics

I realize Swift generics are not like C++ templates where the code is specialized and generated at instantiation, but is there a way to get the following code to specialize the second call?

```
func X1<R>(i: R) {
    print("R")
}

func X1(i: Int) {
    print("Int")
}

func X2<R>(i: R) {
    X1(i: i)
}

X2(i: "s")
X2(i: 1)
X1(i: "s")
X1(i: 1)
```

In particular, the output I see is:

```
R
R
R
Int
```

But I really want the X2 call to X1 for Int to specialize to the X1 Int:

```
R
Int
R
Int
```

I know I can do it by creating another X2 with Int as the type, but I was hoping to avoid that.

**EDIT** A few of the answers suggests adding handling per specialized type (i.e., add a `func X2(i: Int)` or doing type casting `let x = i as? Int`) -- that's what I'm trying to avoid as there could be a lot of specialized types, for example:

```
func X1(i: Double) {
    print("Double")
}

func X1(i: Bool) {
    print("Bool")
}

func X1(i: Float) {
    print("Float")
}
```

Comment: On every version of Swift I tested I got "R", "R", "R", "Int". (Swift 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.1, 3.1.1, 4.0)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the output.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to overload a function such that both a generic and concrete version exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast R in X2:

```
func X2<R>(i: R) { 
   if let x = i as? Int { 
       X1(i: x) 
   } else { 
       X1(i: i) 
   } 
}
```

This will force a call to the Int version of X1. As the compiler will specialize the generics away, all of the casting will probably go away.

Depending on the situation you might be able to use protocol extensions with associated type constraints to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be any better than adding a bunch of specializations for X2.

Answer (score 0):

I only make it work by specialising X2 for Int type:

```
func X1<R>(i: R) {
    print("Any")
}
func X1(i: Int) {
    print("Int")
}

func X2<R>(i: R) {
    X1(i: i)
}
func X2(i: Int) {
    X1(i: i)
}

X2(i: "s")
X2(i: 1)
X1(i: "s")
X1(i: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I mentioned already -- I can only do this by specializing X2, which doesn't really help if I have a lot of specialization for X1.